# initializer list cannot be used on the right hand side of operator ':'

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to implement this `median()` function in `C++`, for some reason, I keep getting: `initializer list cannot be used on the right hand side of operator ':'`

```
template <typename... Args> auto median(Args... args) {
  auto n = sizeof...(args);
  std::array<double, n> numbers = {args...};
  return (n % 2 != 0) ? std::function{[]() { return numbers[n / 2]; }}
                      : std::function{[]() {
                          return (numbers[(n - 1) / 2] + numbers[n / 2]) / 2.0;
                        }};
};
```

**Expected:**

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto v = median(1, 3, 5, 7);
    std::cout << "Median " << v << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** `4.0`

Comment: At the very least, your function `median` returns a `std::function`.

I'm pretty sure that's not what you meant.

Comment: @MarshallClow, no that's now what I really want.

Comment: Could you explain the thought process of using `std::function` and the `return` statement itself here? I really don't see how it comes about.

Comment: @user17732522, I googled for lambda condition, because, I wanted to make the code more simplified and beautiful, so thought of using lambda as a form for condition and based on it return one of the two options.

Comment: I don't know what a "lambda condition" is supposed to be or what it is supposed to simplify. The lambdas and `std::function` just don't belong there. You can remove them and just keep the operands of the inner `return` statements for the operands of the ternary operator. But then your implementation is missing the fundamental step that the range must be sorted in order to have the median in the middle of it. (Your example usage has it pre-ordered, but your problem description doesn't state that as precondition.)

Comment: Lambdas don't capture what they should + n should be constexpr.
https://godbolt.org/z/qMEEb1P3M

Comment: The `function`s that you are returning need to reference the array `numbers`, but that gets destroyed when the function `median` returns.  How are you going to deal with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need `std::function`s and lambdas here. Following compiled and worked without any issue.

```
template <typename... Args> auto median(Args... args) {
  const auto n = sizeof...(args);
  std::array<double, n> numbers = {args...};
  return (n % 2 != 0) ? numbers[n / 2] : (numbers[(n - 1) / 2] + numbers[n / 2]) / 2.0;
};
```

Comment: `n` must be constexpr.